# method in API cause error in model because model is named the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a PhoneNumber model, that's connected with twilio inside it I validate the number, and I think what's happening is I'm calling `response.phone_number` on Twilios API and the model thinks that `phone_humber` is me referencing the `phone_number` in the model. The model is stored like this:

PhoneNumber

- phone_number

so it's PhoneNumber.create(phone_number: "some number")

is there a way to avoid this? Here's my code:

```
  def valid_number
    lookup_client = Twilio::REST::LookupsClient.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
    begin
      response = lookup_client.phone_numbers.get(phone_number)
      response.phone_number
      return true
    rescue => e
      if e.code == 20404
        errors.add(:phone_number, 'number is not valid')
        return false
      else
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
```

the error returns:

```
undefined method `phone_number' for <Twilio::REST::Lookups::PhoneNumber @path=/v1/PhoneNumbers/>:Twilio::REST::Lookups::PhoneNumber
```

Comment: I think it might be happening here: `response = lookup_client.phone_numbers.get(phone_number)` What is phone_number? in there it does not seem like you have defined it?

Comment: phone_number is a column in the model, and the method is inside it so it's referencing it

Comment: No its not referencing to your model. I believe there is no `phone_number` method or attribute for ur response. May be your query `lookup_client.phone_numbers.get(phone_number)` returns no number.

Comment: Where do you have this code? in the controller or in the model?

Comment: Which line does actually produce the error?

Comment: if it's in the model did you try using `self.phone_number` ? Try that.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `phone_number' for
>   Twilio::REST::Lookups::PhoneNumber
>   @path=/v1/PhoneNumbers/:Twilio::REST::Lookups::PhoneNumber

The problem is here in this line

```
response = lookup_client.phone_numbers.get(phone_number)
```

here the ***Rails*** cannot identity what is the `phone_number` actually.

If you have that method in the `model`, then the below should work

```
response = lookup_client.phone_numbers.get(self.phone_number)
```

If you have that method in a `controller` then check the `params` coming into that `action` and do like `params[:phone_number]`

```
response = lookup_client.phone_numbers.get(params[:phone_number])
```